# Elasticsearch geo_point mapping in laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, mapping, geopoints

I'm trying to map my locations as 'geo_point'. I used mysql DB to store point type datas as 'location'. Here's the codes of my model-'GeoSearch'.

```
`protected $mapping = [
    'properties' => [
        'id' => [
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ],
        'Address' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'english'
        ],
        'city' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'english'
        ],
        'area' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'english'
        ],
        'location' => [
            'type' => 'geo_point',
            'ignore_malformed' => true
        ],
    ]
];`
```

But, when I tried to index using scout, `php artisan scout:import "App\GeoSearch"`, following error shows.

`"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapp
  er [location] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [geo_poin
  t]"}]`

Here's an example of my data. As 'location' is stored as spatial data type 'POINT', it is showing in byte string.
`{
            "id": 32817,
            "longitude": "90.36189739",
            "latitude": "23.80241151",
            "Address": "abc",
            "city": "X",
            "area": "Y",
            "location": "0x000000000101000000B2A3AB53299756404C6239D76ACD3740",
        }`

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Join documents you tried to index.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by join documents?

Comment: Give us exemple of data you tried to index (json if possible)

Comment: I've given an example of my data.

Comment: 0x000000000101000000B2A3AB53299756404C6239D76ACD3740 isnot a valid geohash. Elastic reject it.